# ASP ImageButton OnClientClick Confirmation Cancel Button Not Working at IE 8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, confirm

I have Grid Like this :
[image: Grid]

This is my code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" SkinID="Delete" CommandName="Delete"
                                        OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure want to delete?')" />
```

That code works fine at another browser,
But this happened just at IE 8.
Scenario:

-I click delete button

-The popup appears:

[image: popUp]

-I click cancel

-The data Deleted (It should not be deleted, because I click cancel)

Comment: data deleted ? which data ?

Comment: try this OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')) return false;"

Comment: Sorry. I am forgotten. That is at telerik:RadGrid part...

Comment: That code is work at another browser.. But this happened at IE 8